# Matrix multiplication w/ random values wrong output

Tags: c++, matrix, multiplication

I have written a program that gives random values to two matrices and then using multiplication to print out a third matrix. Matrix 1 is 3x3 (rows, columns) and Matrix 2 is (3x2).

My output is as follows:

```
Matrix 1:
  4   6   0
  9   1   5
  4   7   5
Matrix 2:
  4   6
  0   9
  1   5
matrix 1 x matrix 2:
 16  78 97059710
 41  88 218384285
 21 112 97059715
```

As you can see the third matrix gives an extra row / column with weird values. (`97057910` etc.)

Below is my multiply function written in C++:

```
Matrix Matrix::multiply(Matrix one, Matrix two) {

    int n1 = one.data[0].size();
    int n2 = two.data.size();

    int nCommon = one.data.size();

    vector< vector<int> > temp(nCommon);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < nCommon ; i++ )
       temp[i].resize(n2);

    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<nCommon;k++) {
                temp[i][j]= temp[i][j] + one.data[i][k] * two.data[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    const Matrix result = Matrix(temp);
    return result;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this issue? I want to remove that line of weird values and only have two columns.

Comment: `vector< vector<int> > temp(nCommon);` seems suspicious, you probably mean `std::vector<std::vector<int>> temp(n1, std::vector<int>(n2));`

Comment: your first  problem goes back to your understanding of matrix multiplications. Perhaps look it up before anything else. M[3x3] X N[3x2] = P[3x3]  is nonsensical. You can have M[3x3] x N[3x2] = P[3x2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your numbers of rows and columns mixed up. The idea is to multiply A (I x K) by B (K x J), and here's what the code does:

```
int n1 = one.data[0].size(); // this is K
int n2 = two.data.size(); // this is also K

int nCommon = one.data.size(); // this is I

vector< vector<int> > temp(nCommon);

for ( int i = 0 ; i < nCommon ; i++ )
   temp[i].resize(n2);

// temp is now I x K, which is not what was intended,
// and the iteration over rows and columns will not be correct.
```

Try this instead:

```
int n1 = one.data.size(); // this is I
int n2 = two.data[0].size(); // this is J

int nCommon = two.data.size(); // this is K

vector< vector<int> > temp(n1);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < nCommon ; i++ )
   temp[i].resize(n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though one of your matrixes has only two columns, looks like your for-loop will still attempt to access values in the third column of each row.

```
two.data[k][j]
```

k iterates from 0 to `one.data.size()`-1, or 0..2.

j also iterates from 0 to `two.data.size()`-1, also 0..2.

However, according to your description, the `two`'s matrix's second dimension's range is only 0..1.

Undefined behavior. The code is running off past the end of the vector, and reads garbage.